# How to shrink font size in Textblock to fit width of content AND maintain font aspect ratio

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, textblock

Here's the deal: I have this line of XAML

```
<Viewbox Canvas.Left="27" Canvas.Top="479" Width="377" Height="21" Stretch="Fill" 
       StretchDirection="DownOnly" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
  <TextBlock Name="TitleText" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" 
           FontStretch="Normal"  FontStyle="Normal" Foreground="White" Width="377" >some long text here
  </TextBlock>
</Viewbox>
```

I want the font to scale down to fit the contents height and width.
What happens now is that the font scales down, but the Viewbox also scales the content horizontally, making the width of the textbox smaller.
Here's an example

[Example image](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82345626/Uniform.png)

If I set Stretch="Fill" the text will fill the widht, but shrinks only font-size in heigth, making the font look horribly ugly [Like this](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/82345626/Fill.png).

Is it possible to shrink the text to fit inside a frame so that it uses the whole width and height of the container?

Comment: It sounds like maybe you just want the text to wrap to the full width of the available space, without changing the font size?  Or alternatively, to drop the font size to allow the text to fit *without* scaling the entire control.  I'm not sure that a `Viewbox` is the best solution for this.

Comment: It sounds like you just need a multiline `TextBox` with a `ScrollBar` to me... your end users won't thank you for messing with the size of the text... it will make it inconsistent with the rest of the text in the application and for that matter, each text object (I imagine) would be inconsistently sized compared to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continue the work from Marcus:

```
<Viewbox Canvas.Left="27" Canvas.Top="479" Width="377" Height="21" Stretch="Fill" 
        StretchDirection="DownOnly" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
   <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
       <TextBlock Name="TitleText" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" 
            FontStretch="Normal"  FontStyle="Normal" Foreground="White" Width="377" >some long  text here
       </TextBlock>
   </Viewbox>
 </Viewbox>
```

I changed it to

> Stretch="Uniform"

and

> StretchDirection="Both"

and the result seems great, without stretching the word vertically.

Answer (score 1):

You may not set the StretchDirection property of your viewbox to "DownOnly". This setting leads to the effect that the content only gets stretched vertical.

Comment: Hi Jan, thanks for the response. Without the `DownOnly`, then the text also will grow, it should only shrink.

Comment: This is useful for making the long strings fit without making to look odd the strings that already fit. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
<Viewbox Stretch="Uniform">
    <TextBlock Name="TitleText" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" 
       FontStretch="Normal"  FontStyle="Normal" Foreground="White" Width="377">
       some long text here
    </TextBlock>
</Viewbox>
```

Comment: Well, what happens then is that
1) Text don't wrap, the text renders on only one line
2) Because of that, the text is shrinked to a tiny size
So unfortunately that doesn't work. I Need to set the width of the TextBlock so that the TextBlock wraps the text

Comment: I thought that you would added your additional properties onto the `TextBlock` in my example... I just couldn't be bothered to put them all there, but I have now, so give it another try.

Answer (score 0):

Here there is a possible solution using a second ViewBox:

```
<Viewbox Canvas.Left="27" Canvas.Top="479" Width="377" Height="21" Stretch="Fill" 
        StretchDirection="DownOnly" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
   <Viewbox Stretch="Fill" Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
       <TextBlock Name="TitleText" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Left" FontSize="14" 
            FontStretch="Normal"  FontStyle="Normal" Foreground="White" Width="377" >some long  text here
       </TextBlock>
   </Viewbox>
 </Viewbox>
```